# python stdout.flush() does NOT flush last white characters like '\n'

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, flush

I have two programs. First one (`subprocess.cpp`) written in C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char * line = new char[1000];

    // first scan
    scanf("%s\n", line);
    printf("%s\n", line);
    fflush(stdout);

    // second scan
    scanf("%s\n", line);
    printf("%s\n", line);
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

This program simply gets two string from stdin and prints in on stdout, flushing after all.
Here is the second program (`test.py`) written in Python 2.7:

```
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import PIPE
from subprocess import Popen

# create process
my_process = Popen("./subprocess", stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE)

# send initial data
my_process.stdin.write('abc\n')
my_process.stdin.flush()
my_process.stdin.write('xyz\n')
my_process.stdin.flush()

# read data from subprocess
print "Subprocess line 1 :: " + str(my_process.stdout.readline())
print "Subprocess line 2 :: " + str(my_process.stdout.readline())
```

This script should start the subproccess, send and retrieve two strings. Look what is happpening:

```
marcin@marcin-Aspire-7540 ~/Desktop/inzynierka $ g++ subprocess.cpp -o subprocess
marcin@marcin-Aspire-7540 ~/Desktop/inzynierka $ python test.py 
Subprocess line 1 :: abc
```

`test.py` is waiting for the second line from program `subprocess`. Program `subprocess` cannot send the 2nd string because it's waiting for '\n' character.

If I change the second `scanf` in `subprocess.cpp` to `scanf("%s\n", line);` (no `\n`) everything works fine. Same happens when I send one additional line in `test.py`:

```
# send initial data
my_process.stdin.write('abc\n')
my_process.stdin.flush()
my_process.stdin.write('xyz\n')
my_process.stdin.flush()
my_process.stdin.write('ADDITIONAL\n')
my_process.stdin.flush()
```

It seems that Python does NOT send the last \n character after flushing (see example with changed scanf). Adding one additional write and flush in `test.py` proves, that missing \n character is still in the buffer after flush.

What to do with that? How to make Python's flush to flush ALL characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fault is scanf behavior with \n i format strings. It seams that scanf("%s\n") will return after first non-whitespace character after \n while using pipes or after first non-empty line while using terminal (because first non-whitespace character will be flushed after next \n).

The point is that you probably didn't mean to use scanf("%s\n"). My guess is that what you really want is:

```
scanf("%s%*[^\n]", line);
```

which will read word, then discard all characters in the same line.

Comment: Agreed, the problem is the use of '\n' in the scanf format string, not in Python.  Actually, just `scanf("%s", line)` works fine, or even `gets(line)` (depending on the intent).

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea that the problem does not lie in the Python itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `scanf("%s\n", line)`, the second `scanf()` need to read another line before it can find non-whitespace character.

There is a good explanation for similar case [here](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html).

I also checked it with `strace`, Python sends the last `'\n'` character.

```
pid 6611: test.py
pid 6613: subprocess

> strace -f python test.py
[pid  6611] write(4, "abc\n", 4 <unfinished ...>
...
[pid  6611] write(4, "abc\n", 4 <unfinished ...>
...
[pid  6613] read(0, "abc\nxyz\n", 4096) = 8
...
[pid  6613] write(1, "abc\n", 4)        = 4
[pid  6611] <... read resumed> "a", 1)  = 1
[pid  6613] read(0,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  6611] read(5, "b", 1)             = 1
[pid  6611] read(5, "c", 1)             = 1
[pid  6611] read(5, "\n", 1)            = 1
...
[pid  6611] write(1, "Subprocess line 1 :: abc\n", 25Subprocess line 1 :: abc) = 25
[pid  6611] write(1, "\n", 1)           = 1
[pid  6611] read(5,
```